# Dropdown Select Form, Go to URL On SUBMIT

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

Is there a simple way to have a user go to a URL from a dropdown list on SUBMIT, rather than onChange.

I have this code:

```
<form name="cityselect">
<select name="menu" onChange="top.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" value="GO">
<option selected="selected">Select One</option>
<option value="http://www.domain-one.com">London</option>
<option value="http://www.domain-two.com">Glasgow</option>
</select>
```

Tried changing onChange to onSubmit, but it doesn't work.

Comment: a select doesn not have a submit even. Submit event is with the form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this instead.

**Also:** You'll want to keep your JavaScript separated from your HTML. Do not use `onchange` or similar HTML attributes. While it's technically not wrong, it's bad from a code quality/maintainability perspective.

```js
var goBtn = document.getElementById("goBtn");
var menu = document.getElementById("menu");

goBtn.onclick = function() {
  window.location = menu.value;
}
```

```html
<select id="menu">
  <option selected="selected">Select One</option>
  <option value="http://www.domain-one.com">London</option>
  <option value="http://www.domain-two.com">Glasgow</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="goBtn" value="GO!">
```

Does this work for you?

Comment: Works like a dream! Thank you :)

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `onsubmit` event on the `<form>` element, but you'll want to preventDefault on the event, and for the `onsubmit` event you need to use a `return`:

```
<form name="cityselect" onsubmit="return redirectTo(this)">
  <select name="menu" value="GO">
    <option selected="selected">Select One</option>
    <option value="http://www.domain-one.com">London</option>
    <option value="http://www.domain-two.com">Glasgow</option>
  </select>
</form>

<script>
  function redirectTo(elem) {
    event.preventDefault();
    top.location.href = elem.firstElementChild.options[elem.firstElementChild.selectedIndex].value
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Tried this, but it appends the URL to the end of my current URL with ?menu before it. i.e. domain.com?menu=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain-one.com .. instead of going direct to the URL.

Comment: I've updated my answer to fix this issue - need to use `return` keyword and preventDefault on the event